# How get the path of a java file selected in the pacake explorer in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-jdt

I have this code in an Eclipse plugin. I need to get the path of whatever file. For instances of `IFile` it works, but for `ICompilationUnit` I have no idea.

```
final IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
final IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) window.getSelectionService().getSelection("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer");
    
final Object firstElement = selection.getFirstElement();
String selectedFile = "";
                
if (firstElement instanceof IFile){
    IPath loc = ((IFile) firstElement).getLocation();
    if (loc != null){
        selectedFile = loc.toOSString();
        if(!selectedFile.endsWith(".java")){
            selectedFile = "";
        }
    }
} else {
    if(firstElement instanceof ICompilationUnit){   
        CompilationUnit comUnit = ( CompilationUnit)firstElement;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
IResource resource = (IResource)Platform.getAdapterManager().getAdapter(firstElement, IResource.class);

if (resource != null) {
    IPath path = resource.getLocation();

    ...
}
```

Comment: And when the resource is not a IFile instance, for example CompilationUnit?

Comment: Actually as you just want the path you can just use `IResource.getLocation`. Hopefully the adapter manager will be able to find the `IResource` matching the compilation unit.

Comment: Yes, the adapter manager should be able to convert from a CompilationUnit to an IResource

Comment: If the question is about eclipse and there is an answer from Greg - you don't need to search any further :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if firstElement is a `CompilationUnit`, not an `ICompilationUnit`, as it is the only one implementation of `ICompilationUnit`. Than you can call `getCorrespondingResource()` method.

Comment: Now there is not access to eclipse help page. I have not the getCorrecpondingResource() method in the CompilationUnit class. Which import I nedd?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
String path = iCompilationUnit.getResource().getFullPath();
```

This will give you the entire path for the selected `ICompilationUnit`.